# File does not get created in script (Mikrotik)

Tags: router, mikrotik

Hello I've got a following script:

```
:local filename "test.txt"
:local content "This is a test."
   
/file print file=$filename where name="";
:delay 5
/file set $filename contents=$content;
```

Policies: read, write, test

But for some reason, requested file does not get created. Why is that? My hardware is Mikrotik hAP ac3, with RouterOS 7.2.3.

Answer (score -1):

`:local` variables are not cached in Terminal, but only in scripts.

```
:local filename "test.txt"
:put $filename # variable is empty
```

You can circumvent this by either using `:global` instead or using `{ }` brackets:

```
{
  :local filename "test.txt"
  :local content "This is a test."
   
  /file print file=$filename where name="";
  :delay 5
  /file set $filename contents=$content;
}
```

Tested with RouterOS v7.4.1.

Side note: File names (unfortunately) always end with .txt. Maximum file content size is 4096 characters.